# Prove that $S = \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : x>0, y>0\}$ is open.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Prove that $S = \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : x>0, y>0\}$ is open.

Can anyone help me, I need to prove this statement only by the use of a ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y) \in S $. Let $r = \min(x,y)$. Then $B((x,y),r) \subset S$.

To see this, suppose $(x',y') \in B((x,y),r)$. Then $(x'-x)^2+(y-y')^2 < r^2$. This implies $\max   \ (|x'-x|,|y'-y|) < r$.

This gives $x' > x-r$, and since $r \le x$, we have $x'>0$. Similarly, $y'>0$. Hence $(x',y') \in S$, and so $B((x,y),r) \subset S$.

Comment: Why does $|x' -x|<r$ imply that $x' > x-r$?

Comment: Because $x'-x > -r$ is certainly a necessary condition for $|x'-x|<r$.

Comment: $|a|<b$ iff $-b < a < b$.

Answer (score 4):

A picture may be helpful for you. Let the radius of the ball smaller than both $x$ and $y$. That is OK.

**PS:
You would want to know $A$ is open iff for any $x\in A$, then there exists an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq A$.**

[image]

Comment: Did you do this with paint?

Comment: Yes. I draw it by myself.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** It is necessary and sufficient to show that around every $p = (x,y) \in S$, there is *some* ball $U_p$ around $p$ such that $U_p \subseteq S$.

What could the maximal radius of $U_p$ be?