# How do I check whether this set is open or not in $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Question is given as $S= \{(x,y) ∈ \Bbb R^2 \mid 4x + 3y > 12\}$

So the way how I approached it is, say $(x_1,y_1) \in S$ which is any arbitrary point in $S$. Now $B((x_1,y_1), r)$ ($r$ is the radius of open ball). So $$B((x_1,y_1),r) = \bigl\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n\mid \bigl((x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2\bigr)^{1/2}  < r\bigr\}$$ so we will prove that $(x,y) \in B((x_1,y_1), r)$.

Consider $|x-x_1| = \left((x-x_1)^2\right)^{1/2} <\left((x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2\right)^{1/2} < r$, 
 which means that $|x-x_1| < r$ which ultimately means  $x_1 - r < x < x_1 + r$, but after this point I don't know what to do, I don't know what to take as $r$ in this problem.

Comment: Have a look here at this site for very similar questions, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358070/prove-that-s-x-y-in-bbb-r2-x0-y0-is-open).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the point to line distance formula, the distance from some $(x_0, y_0)$ to $ax + by+c=0$ is $$ \left|\frac{ax_0 + by_0 +c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right|$$ and in your case we're interested in the line $4x +3y-12=0$. In particular, then, the distance between $(x_0, y_0)$ and that point is $$ d=\frac{|4x_0+3y_0-12|}{5}$$ and your set is precisely defined to be the $(x_0, y_0)$ so that the numerator of that expression is positive, so the distance is actually just $$d=\frac{4x_0 +3y_0 - 12 }{5}$$ Thus, given any point $(x_0, y_0) \in S$ one can draw an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ and get points only in $S$ if one draws a ball of radius, say $$ \epsilon = \frac{4x_0 +3y_0 - 12 }{10}$$ and that's really just the fact that the shortest distance to any point outsider of $S$ is $d$. So, in particular, $S$ is an open set, because we can draw a ball of the radius $\epsilon$ given above containing only points in $S$ around any point in $S$.

Comment: So basically in questions like these, our main objective is to show that there exists a radius  within which, our (x,y) belongs in. SO in this case im imagining a straight line intercepting the x and y axis and our ball should be in the shaded region. And that radius we will find is from center of that circle to our straight line given by the question?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The definition of an Open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$  is that given any point $p_0 \in S$ there exists some $\epsilon >0$ so that every point $p_1$ with distance $0 < d(p_0, p_1) < \epsilon$ has $p_1 \in S$. We want to show that we can draw a ball of some radius $\epsilon$ around $p_0$ so that the resulting ball is totally contained in $S$.  So, the strait line distance between $p_0$ and the line is the minimum distance at which that ball has points no longer in $S$. Since we can calculate that radius, if we draw a circle of radius $\epsilon$ smaller than it, that ball is in $S$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line for more on how to calculate that distance, if that's a calculation you don't happen to be familiar with, too.

Comment: Noted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Lets define the function $g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x,y)=4x+3y$

This function is continous since is the sum of two continous functions (four times the proyection to X and 3 times the proyection to Y) .

Since $V=\langle 0;+\infty \rangle$ is a open set and $g^{-1}(V)=\{(x,y) ∈ \Bbb R^2 \mid 4x + 3y > 12\}$, hence, by continuity of $g$, we have that $\{(x,y) ∈ \Bbb R^2 \mid 4x + 3y > 12\}$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for an elementary solution, and for this I think you should refer to the other answer provided (so take this "answer" as more of an extended comment that provides an alternative approach to solving).

Define the function $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = 4x + 3y$. Now, $f$ is just a (linear) polynomial function hence it is continuous. One key property of continuous functions is that preimages of open sets is open. In other words, if $U$ is an open subset of the target space $\Bbb{R}$, then the preimage of $U$ under $f$,
\begin{align}
f^{-1}[U] := \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: f(x,y) \in U\}
\end{align}
is an open subset of the domain $\Bbb{R}^2$.

In your particular case, we have that
\begin{align}
S&:= \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : 4x+3y > 12 \} \\
&= \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) > 12 \} \\
&= f^{-1}\left[ (12,\infty) \right]
\end{align}
Note that $(12,\infty)$ is an open subset of the target space $\Bbb{R}$; now since $f$ is continuous, it follows that $S = f^{-1}[(12,\infty)]$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

---

This property gives an easy way of checking whether certain sets are open. For example, the "exterior of a unit ball"
\begin{align}
B := \{x \in \Bbb{R}^n: \lVert x\rVert> 1 \}
\end{align}
is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$ because it can be seen as the preimage of an open set under a continuous mapping. More precisely, define $f$ to be the norm function: $f(x) = \lVert x \rVert$. Then, $B = f^{-1}[(1,\infty)]$ is open.